# Matching parameters of a function with Regex

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

What I have so far: `\w+\(((".+")|(\d+))+\)`
I'm not sure how to go about matching more than one paramter separated by a comma. How can I capture the parameters (and function names) of the following test cases?

`scroll("foo")`
`scroll("foo",55)`
`scroll("foo","bar")`
`scroll("foo","bar",55)`
`scroll(55)`
`scroll(55,"foo")`
`scroll(55, 13,"foo","bar")`

For example, in the last one the groups must be `scroll`, `55`, `13`, `"foo"`, and `"bar"`.

Edit: Language is AS3

Comment: I guess you want also to handle `scroll("scroll(55,scroll(5))")`. Right ? Then the engine you want to use is worth to precise. See the description of the [regex] tag.

Comment: It is not solvable for an unbounded number of parameters (because you can't have an unbounded number of capturing groups). Is there a maximal number of parameters?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm not interested in functions as parameters

Comment: @Aaron There's no programmatic way of doing this? I'd think there would be.

Comment: @OlinKirkland read again. There are quotes. This is just a string as parameter and this kind of thing makes it more complex and we *need* to know the regex flavor.

Comment: Also a best practice would be to use a parser dedicated to the language you're handling, which would probably solve by itself a number of problems you might encounter with regex.

Comment: @OlinKirkland not to my knowledge. You could have a capturing group match all the parameters, then split that result around a separator (`,`), but I don't think you can say "I'll have up to x occurences of this pattern, whose content I want to be able to access in the n+x th group"

Comment: @DenysSéguret Sorry - yes, you're right. `"scroll(55,scroll(5))"` will be treated the same way as `"foo"` - a string and nothing else.

Comment: @Aaron The language I'm using is AS3, so I've got a `.split(",")` command at my disposal. At the very least I want to match (without groups) the strings to make sure they're valid calls.

Comment: So, in the last example, you will have 5 groups in regex results, group 1 = "scroll", group 2 = 55 , and group 3 = 13, and so on .. is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Ibrahim Correct.

Comment: Does you SWF run in a web browser? I have a funny idea that will take care of all the `"scroll(55, 13,"foo","bar", "now, we are \"screwed\"")"` cases.

Comment: `scroll(55, 13,"foo","bar", "now(), we are \"screwed\")")` -- that would be a finer example of how things may go wrong. :)

Comment: I'm running it in Adobe Air, actually - but it's a Console.swc intended for a variety of applications (both web and desktop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this lengthy regex:

```
(\"?\w+\"?)\((\"?\w+\"?)(?:[,\s]+(\"?\w+\"?))?(?:[,\s]+(\"?\w+\"?))?(?:[,\s]+(\"?\w+\"?))?\)?
```

The code above is set to capture up to five parameters. You can adjust that by adding/removing this code `(?:[,\s]+(\"?\w+\"?))?` based on your needs.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/o1RRSG/1

Comment: I see that it works up to five parameters, but how can I get it to support `n` parameters?

Comment: @OlinKirkland If you're asking about unbounded number of parameters, you cannot do that. You will have to specify the maximum number of parameters that you want your code to match. This maximum number can be 5 as the way current code is set or 10 or 50 or 5000. It is up to you. Allowing more parameters can be done by adding more of this code `(?:[,\s]+(\"?\w+\"?))?`

Comment: I can't do it? At all? There's no way, even outside of regex?

Comment: @OlinKirkland You can't do that only inside Regex. outside Regex is another story.

Comment: Gonna mark this as the "answer", but I wish there was a way of parsing an indefinite number of parameters.

Comment: how would I get this to work with sentences within quotes? If there's a space inside quotes it breaks.

Comment: @OlinKirkland just replace `\w+` with `[\w\s]+`, and it will not break. Do that for all of them except the first one.

Answer (score 1):

i hope i'm in right way
you want to split for example

this: `scroll (     55,    13,    "foo",      "bar"   )`

to its function name and arguments like

this:  `scroll`     (       `55`,     `13`,    `"foo"`,      `"bar"`       )

> a better result of expression:
>
> [image]

**i just assume additional white spaces for more accuracy**

the regex fot would be :

> **[^\t (,)]**

Comment: @DenysSéguret so please tell me a breaking case

Comment: Just look at the comments below the question

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you may not like it, but it's *flawless* as long as you have [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call()) backed with JS available. And it's funny. (While doing this with reg exps is the opposite of fun.)

The idea is to let JS do its `eval`. The manual says you have to pass a function name to `ExternalInterface.call()`, which is not true: pass just any code that evaluates to a function reference. This way you can inject any JS code into the page where your SWF resides (which is why `AllowScriptAccess` is such a terribly dangerous attribute).

```
public class Test extends Sprite
{
    public function Test()
    {
        var test = "scroll(55, 13,\"foo\",\"bar\", \"now(), we are \\\"screwed\\\")\")";
        trace(test);
        var details = parseFunctionCall(test);
        trace(details[0]);
        for (var i = 1; i<details.length; i++) {
            trace("\t"+i+": "+typeof(details[i])+" "+details[i]);
        }
    }

    private function parseFunctionCall(input:String):Array
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available) {
            var split:RegExp = /^(\w+)\((.+)\)$/;
            var info = split.exec(input);
            var inject = "(function(){return ["+info[2]+"];})";
            var params = ExternalInterface.call(inject);
            params.unshift(info[1]);
            return params;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/*
Output:

scroll
    1: number 55
    2: number 13
    3: string foo
    4: string bar
    5: string now(), we are "screwed")
*/
```

Comment: This has to be self contained in an .swc I can drop into any project. Otherwise its moot since I want to run in Adobe Air as simply as possible.

Comment: It's just an idea that's easy to implement and takes care of the problem... Albeit only for web projects. Otherwise I don't see the way around without some tedious handiwork, unless you somehow forbid commas and quotes in the string parameters (which I doubt is the case). So, I think you'll end up with a loop and counting separators. The thing you are looking for is called "string tokenizer function", a function that performs lexical scan for a given language syntax.